# Looking for Experimental Result Data for Bell's Inequality, especially at 60 degrees

Tags: quantum-spin, bells-inequality

I've been looking for an experiment (for Bell's Inequality, using Bell's 60 degree test angle) which shows counts and resulting correlation percentage calculated.

I want to see if a) for 99 runs 66 correlations and 33 non-correlations is 50%; or if b) for 100 runs 75 correlations and 25 non-correlations is 50%.

I'm skeptical of the stigma around hidden variables, and many explanations are pretty hand-wavy without concrete evidence; so please don't just respond with 'ya situation X is 50%'.

What exactly does '50%' correlation at 60 degrees actually mean?

Comment: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/bell-theorem/ would be a good start if you want to see the theory of how this came about

Comment: Yes; that page comes up in search engines often too.  There is a list of experiment years and names, but no links to them; on wikipedia there's a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_test which has some links to some experiments, but they are not the 50% correlation; CHSH, GHZ, ... The earliest linked experiment is a stack of polarizers, which is a different problem than 2 independent channels.  And most links are just explainers without actual data.

Comment: Hint : if the function for the results are $A(a\lambda)$,$\ldots C(c,\lambda)$ then with 3 points of measurements yields 3 covariances. These can classically be exact, i.e. 1 or -1, but this implies a contradiction. So the domain of $\lambda_i$ for the ith covariance cannot intersect. This in turns forbids the usual 1+1, 1-1 reasoning since the factorization is no more possible.

Comment: @Cretin2 https://d3x0r.github.io/STFRPhysics/math/indexBellInequality.html this fits the 3 known points.  It's only a few percentage off depending on how you look at it no more than 3%.  There is at least 3% experimental apparatus error.  I was looking for specific experiment measured quantities though, because of this 3% error.  https://github.com/d3x0r/STFRPhysics/blob/master/QuantizedProbability.md more detailed presentation than a graph.

Comment: @Decker Thanx. I was considering just theoretical aspects. Another approach is : let consider the classical covariance with : $A(a,\lambda)=sign(cos(a-\lambda))\Rightarrow Cov(a,b)=-1+\frac{2}{\pi}(b-a),a<b\in\{0,\pi\}$. Then one could consider the change $a=\frac{\pi}{2}\cos a'\Rightarrow Cov(a,b)=-1+\cos a'-\cos b'$. Then a rigid coordinates transform setting $a'=0\Rightarrow b'\rightarrow b'-a'$ sets the covariance to the quantum one.